# C# How to import a Uint from my Mainwindow.xaml.cs to a Program.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For better understanding, im working on a program that can track the angle of my arms and legs (with the kinect) and send it to a NXT Mindstorm Robot.
Im pretty new to Visual Studio and C#, but i managed to get the program track my body and the angles in real time. 
My Problem now is the fact, that im not able to get the angles to my robot in real time. I tried to send the data directy after scanning the angle, but that caused an error cause of the loop there. So i added a console file with the MindSqualls.dll (Libary for Mindstorms) and wanted to run it there.

My question is now, if its possible to send the angles to the console application in real time, when the Mainwindow.xaml.cs is running.

This is the part of my program where the angle is constructed. Need to convert cause brick.MotorB.Run only works with Uint.

```
        double AngleRightArm = Vector3D.AngleBetween(ShoulderElbowR, NewPShoulderR); //Angle Right Arm
        double AngleLeftArm = Vector3D.AngleBetween(ShoulderElbowL, NewPShoulderL); //Angle Left Arm


        UInt16 RobotArmR = Convert.ToUInt16(AngleRightArm);
        UInt16 RobotArmL = Convert.ToUInt16(AngleLeftArm);
```

Here is my console application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NKH.MindSqualls;
using WpfApplication1;

namespace RoboterMove
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a NXT brick,
            // and use Bluetooth on COM40 to communicate with it.
            NxtBrick brick = new NxtBrick(NxtCommLinkType.USB, 0);

        // Attach motors to port B and C on the NXT.
        brick.MotorB = new NxtMotor();
        brick.MotorC = new NxtMotor();


        // Connect to the NXT.
        brick.Connect();

        // Run them at 75% power, for a 3600 degree run.
        brick.MotorB.Run(75, RobotArmR);
        brick.MotorC.Run(75, RobotArmL);

        // Disconnect from the NXT.
        brick.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

}

Since both applications are in the same project, there should be a way to get that work, but everything i tried didnt really worked or made the applications crashed.

Thanks :)

Comment: It might be a better idea to move this to your WPF project, unless there's a requirement for a console application to handle the data acquisition.

Comment: Tried the other answer first, but at the end i just made another method in my main program and it works. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Add try-catch block to your code, analyze the exception and make a correction by yourself, or add it to your question:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
try{
            // Create a NXT brick,
            // and use Bluetooth on COM40 to communicate with it.
            NxtBrick brick = new NxtBrick(NxtCommLinkType.USB, 0);

        // Attach motors to port B and C on the NXT.
        brick.MotorB = new NxtMotor();
        brick.MotorC = new NxtMotor();


        // Connect to the NXT.
        brick.Connect();

        // Run them at 75% power, for a 3600 degree run.
        brick.MotorB.Run(75, RobotArmR);
        brick.MotorC.Run(75, RobotArmL);

        // Disconnect from the NXT.
        brick.Disconnect();
}
catch(Exception ex){}
    }
```

Hope this may help.